# Android ksoap nested soap objects gives unable to read request error

Tags: java, android, soap, ksoap2, android-ksoap2

I'm trying to do the following soap request on Android using KSOAP. It contains a list of nested soap objects. However, I must be doing something wrong as I get an error back.

The request I am trying to generate is as follows:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soap12:Body>
    <SetAttendanceMarks xmlns="http://hostname.net/">
      <strSessionToken>string</strSessionToken>
      <LessonMarks>
        <Count>int</Count>
        <LessonMarks>
          <LessonMark>
            <StudentId>int</StudentId>
            <EventInstanceId>int</EventInstanceId>
            <Mark>string</Mark>
          </LessonMark>
          <LessonMark>
            <StudentId>int</StudentId>
            <EventInstanceId>int</EventInstanceId>
            <Mark>string</Mark>
          </LessonMark>
        </LessonMarks>
      </LessonMarks>
    </SetAttendanceMarks>
  </soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>
```

My code is as follows:

```
public boolean setAttendanceMarks(List<Mark> list) throws Exception
{
    boolean result = false;

    String methodName = "SetAttendanceMarks";
    String soapAction = getHost() + "SetAttendanceMarks";

    SoapObject lessMarksN = new SoapObject(getHost(), "LessonMarks");

    for (Mark m : list)
    {
        PropertyInfo smProp =new PropertyInfo();
        smProp.setName("LessonMark");
        smProp.setValue(m);
        smProp.setType(Mark.class);

        lessMarksN.addProperty(smProp);
    }

    PropertyInfo cProp =new PropertyInfo();
    cProp.setName("Count");
    cProp.setValue(list.size());
    cProp.setType(Integer.class);

    SoapObject lessMarks = new SoapObject(getHost(), "LessonMarks");
    lessMarks.addProperty(cProp);
    lessMarks.addSoapObject(lessMarksN);

    PropertyInfo sProp =new PropertyInfo();
    sProp.setName("strSessionToken");
    sProp.setValue(mSession);
    sProp.setType(String.class);

    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(getHost(), methodName); 
    request.addProperty(sProp);
    request.addSoapObject(lessMarks);


    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER12);
    envelope.dotNet = true;
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(getURL());
    androidHttpTransport.debug = true;

    androidHttpTransport.call(soapAction, envelope);

    String a = androidHttpTransport.requestDump;
    String b = androidHttpTransport.responseDump;

    SoapObject resultsRequestSOAP = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn; 

    SoapObject res = (SoapObject) resultsRequestSOAP.getProperty(0);

    String resultStr = res.getPropertyAsString("Result");

    if (resultStr.contentEquals("OK"))
    {
        result = true;
    }

    return result;
}
```

The error I get is as follows:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<soap:Body>
<soap:Fault>
<soap:Code>
<soap:Value>soap:Sender</soap:Value>
</soap:Code>
<soap:Reason>
<soap:Text xml:lang="en">Server was unable to read request. ---&gt; There is an error in XML document (1, 383). ---&gt; The specified type was not recognized: name='LessonMarks', namespace='http://gsdregapp.net/', at &lt;LessonMarks xmlns='http://gsdregapp.net/'&gt;.</soap:Text>
</soap:Reason>
<soap:Detail />
</soap:Fault>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Can anybody tell me what I am doing wrong? I will be most grateful for any assistance!

Answer (score 1):

The namespace that you're using it's not been recognized by your ws server.

```
SoapObject request = new SoapObject(getHost(), methodName);
```

It looks like should be this way:

```
SoapObject request = new SoapObject("http://hostname.net/", methodName);
```

Make shure that getHost() and getURL() are retrieving the same hostname, because the namespace expected by the host on getURL() is not the same sent by getHost().

If your not shure about wich namespace to use, use SoapUI to read wsdl easily and find the correct namespace

Comment: Thanks for the help. Unfortunately It was quite a tight deadline for this project so had to take another approach. I decided to construct the XML then upload it to the server using a standard HTTP Post. Bit more timeconsuming, but did the job. If I get time in the future I will see if your suggestion works and report back. Thanks again!